# Create a loop to transform several images to vectors and join them into a dataframe

Tags: r, image, loops, dataframe, transformation

I need your help and advices

I have to develop a script in R that saves the vectors resulting from the transformation of several images in a data frame that will have as many rows as images (1000) and as many columns
as variables (4096). The data frame will be exported to a csv file.

I have tried a loop so that it reads the images and transforms them one by one and then join them in a matrix or data frame. I'm new to this... I am lost...
I share you what I have tried.
Any idea or improvement?

```
set.seed(1234)
mypath = "C:/dataset/dataset/effusion/" #file where the images are
files <- list.files(path=mypath, pattern=".png$")
length(files)

for (i in files){
 im <- readImage(mypath[i], header = FALSE)
 grises <- rgb_2gray(im[i])
 # Resize the image to a size of 64 x64 pixels:
 resiz = resizeImage(grises[i], width = 64, height = 64, method = 'nearest')
 # Convert to vector:
 im.convert <- as.vector(resiz[i])
 out <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, im.convert)) # create a data frame
     }
  return(out)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Because this is not a reproducible example, given the impossibility of sharing the image folder, could you be more precise about what the problem is? Does your code work? What sort of improvements do you need?

Comment: Thank you very much for your message
My problem is that the loop does not work, no error comes out, the created table simply does not contain anything ... And the truth is that I don't understand why.

What I am looking for is to read images from the same folder, transform them and convert them to vector. Later create a .csv with the information of all of them.

If I do it image by image it works, but the idea is to do them all in one step.

I hope I have explained myself. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problem with your code and I suggest you review how to write a loop (no need to use `return` if you are not in a function, for example - also you are putting the i index where is not needed). 
This should work to get you a numeric matrix:

```
library(OpenImageR)
mypath = "C:/dataset/dataset/effusion/" #file where the images are
files = list.files(path=mypath, pattern=".png$", full.names = TRUE) # add full.names option to get full path
out = numeric()
for (f in files){
  im = readImage(f)
  grises = rgb_2gray(im)
  # Resize the image to a size of 64 x64 pixels:
  resiz = resizeImage(grises, width = 64, height = 64, method = 'nearest')
  # Convert to vector:
  out = rbind(out, as.vector(resiz))
}
out
```

Comment: I have edited the answer. I suspect the reason it comes out empty is that in the previous version I have changed the matching pattern from `png` to `jpg` because I was testing with some jpg files. If that is the case, `list.files()` returns an empty vector so the loop simply goes directly to the end. Forgive me for lecturing you, but I can see you are at the beginning. When you face a simple problem like this, try to decompose what you are doing in single steps. Execute the code line by line, check the value of the variables at every step, read the documentation of the functions you are using

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!!!!  with your solution now works perfectly! thank you!